# When we close a resource,is the object instantiated with it destructed?

Tags: java, resources

My doubt mainly arises while reading sockets, within the following code:

```
 String hostName = args[0];
    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    try (
        Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
        PrintWriter out =
            new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdIn =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in))
    ) {
        String userInput;
        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(userInput);
            System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
        }
```

Link:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/EchoClient.java

In the above code, as I understand, PrintWriter and BufferedReader are the resources, however I also read in the trywithreasources block, as soon as it ends, all resources within it are closed. But if closing of the resource implies destruction of the object, that would mean stdIn and in are destroyed and it is a separate instance outside the block. Is it so?

Comment: It is so. `System.in` will be closed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't think System.in will be closed by the try-with-resource because it is not declared in the "with-resource" part of the try block.

Comment: @dkatzel `stdIn` is declared in the `try-with-resources`. When its `close()` gets called, it will cascade to the `Reader` it wraps, and so on.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis oh your right .  I thought you meant `System.in`.

Comment: @dkatzel Yes, I mean the object referenced by `System.in`. It will be closed when `stdIn` gets closed.

Comment: @Sotirios Okay, this maybe exceeding the realm of the original question, but if you don't mind further referring to the linked code,how are stdIn and in actually receiving the input that they are processing?

Comment: `System.in` is initially set using a `native` method call tying it to the Java process' standard input stream.

Comment: @Sotirios Understood, so now separate instances(other than those in try-with-resource) of inStd and in accept separate inputs from the Java process' standard input stream,saying this would be correct?
And even though one of the resources during initialization BufferedReader uses System.in,the PrintWriter uses a different output stream,does this bear any implication on the use of out object in contrast to inStd?

Comment: In your code, after your `try` block, if you try to read anything from `System.in`, it will fail. This will not affect the `System.out` in any way.

Comment: @Sotirios Okay. Thank you so much for bearing with me, this cleared up quite a few concepts for me. However,still have a long way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The try-with-resource statement will only close resources declared in the parentheses between the inside the try.

```
 try ( /*anything declared here will be closed*/) {


  }
```

The when the try ends, the try with resource will call `close()` on any resource declared.  This doesn't necessarily "destroy" an object like a destructor in C, but it is often used that way.  The variable will also fall out of scope outside the try so it can be garbage collected.

IN your example `stdIn` wraps `System.in` so `System.in` WILL BE CLOSED.  However since it is still in scope after the try, it will not be garbage collected.  (but you can't write to it anymore)

Try-with-resource is just "syntatic sugar" and will be compiled into something like this:

```
    Socket echoSocket =null
    PrintWriter out =null
    BufferedReader in =null
    BufferedReader stdIn =null
  try{


   echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
    out =
        new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    in =
        new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
    stdIn =
        new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String userInput;
    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(userInput);
        System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
    }
  }finally{
   if(stdIn !=null){
      try{
        stdIn.close()
      }catch(Exception e){
      //surpress exception if needed
     }
   }
  if(in !=null){
     try{
        in.close()
      }catch(Exception e){
      //surpress exception
     }
   }
   if(out !=null){
     try{
        out.close()
      }catch(Exception e){
       //surpress exception
     }
   }
   if(echoSocket !=null){
     try{
        echoSocket.close()
      }catch(Exception e){
        //surpress exception
     }
  }
}
```

Notice that the resources are closed in reverse order to solve the nesting issue. If something threw an exception in the try block AND something else threw an exception in the finally block, then the "surpress exception" gets added to the original Exception object which can be retrieve via the new `Throwable.getSuppressed()`  method. This is so the stacktrace correctly shows the original exception that was thrown inside the try.

for more information about try-with-resource see Oracle's tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Okay, that clears that up. Thank you. Co-incidentally that link is already opened in one of my tabs, have just started networking after going through Input/Output,it's just getting a bit over-whelming.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `try-with-resources`, let's take only the part wrapping `System.in`.

```
try (
    ...
    BufferedReader stdIn =
        new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in))
)
```

`stdIn` is an object that wraps an `InputStreamReader` object that wraps an `InputStream` object. That `InputStream` object is (unless you've changed it) the Java process' standard input.

When you exit the `try` block, it will call `stdIn.close()`, which will cascade and call `close()` on the `InputStreamReader` which will cascade and call `close()` on the object referenced by `System.in`.

There is no destruction in Java. If the objects referenced by the variables above become unreachable from within your program, they will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

> if closing of the resource implies destruction of the object

It doesn't. There is no such thing as 'destruction' in Java.

> that would mean stdIn and in are destroyed

No it doesn't.

> and it is a separate instance outside the block. Is it so?

No.